# How to set up page view in Scrivener?

Tags: software, screenwriting, scrivener

I'm editing a screenplay in Scrivener and would feel more comfortable if It was in page view, but it isn't. The obvious solution is to go into "File" - "Page Set-up" - "A4" and click OK, but Scrivener doesn't work like that.

Could someone explain how to go into page view if that is possible? Failing this, I would not know how many pages my screenplay is, how much I should edit, and whether Scrivener will add *(more)* at the end of dialogue at the end of a page.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you're writing on a *new text* rather than a *scene* because Page View will not work for *scene*. Once you're on your *new text*, go to View, then Text Editing, and one of the options will be Page View. Click on this and then make sure you're in Screenwriting mode by going to Format, then Scriptwriting, and then Script Mode. Hope this helps.